# Erro com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Boa galera, estou com esse erro e não consigo ver a solução. Estou trabalhando no meu primeiro projeto pós faculdade e estou precisando de uma orientação.

Eu tenho as tabelas: Cliente, OrdemDeServico, Orcamento, Servico e OrcamentoTemServico.

As tabelas Cliente, Ordem de serviço, Orcamento e Sevico realizam todas as operações dao conforme programado. O erro acontece quando tento inserir serviços na tabela OrcamentoTemServico.

Abaixo vou colocar um exemplo de teste que fiz e o erro que ocorre:

```
public OrcamentoTemServicoDaoTest() {
}

@Test
public void insetir() {
    Cliente c = new Cliente();
    c.setCPF("79167357504");
    OrdemDeServico ods = new OrdemDeServico();
    ods.setNumeroOS(874);
    Orcamento o = new Orcamento();
    o.setID(1);
    Servico s = new Servico();
    s.setID(1);
    s.setServico("teste");
    s.setPrecoVenda(100);
    OrcamentoTemServico ots = new OrcamentoTemServico();
    ots.setOrcamentoID(o);
    ots.setOrdemDeServicoNumeroOS(ods);
    ots.setOrdemDeServicoClienteCPF(c);
    ots.setQuantidade(1);
    ots.setServicoID(s);
    ots.setValor(100);
    ots.setValorTotal(100);
    OrcamentoTemServicoDao otsdao = new OrcamentoTemServicoDao();
    otsdao.insert(ots);
}
```

Diz que o teste foi aprovado porem apresenta o erro e nenhuma informação é salva na minha tabela OrcamentoTemServico:

Erro com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gtsassist`.`ORCAMENTO_has_SERVICO`, CONSTRAINT `fk_ORCAMENTO_has_SERVICO_ORCAMENTO1` FOREIGN KEY (`ORCAMENTO_ID`, `ORCAMENTO_ORDEM_DE_SERVICO_NUMERO_OS`, `ORCAMENTO_ORDEM_DE_SERVICO_CLIENTE_C)

Desde já, agradeço muito pelo retorno da solução.

Comment: Você relacionou as chaves estrangeiras da tabela que recebe os dados com as tabelas que estão no banco ? "a foreign key constraint fails ".

Comment: Seria legal editar a pergunta porque o código Java é meio irrelevante, é um problema de SQL.

Answer (score -2):

Quando eu fiz um método para deletar Usuário do meu banco de dados, retornou esse erro, e o motivo do erro era que o Usuário na qual eu estava tentando deletar, estava com Pedidos ligados a ele, e se eu deletasse, deletaria também os Pedidos, então, adicionei um novo Usuário pra testar, deletei o mesmo, e funcionou normalmente. Tente ver se o que você está inserindo ou deletando, está ligado a outras classes.

Comment: Sua resposta me fez entender o erro. Eu não posso adicionar ou atualizar uma linha filha, ou seja, os valores das minhas FK devem ser capturadas do resultset e eu estava setando direto.

Answer (score -2):

Segue a solução.

```
@Test
public void insert() {
    ClienteDao cdao = new ClienteDao();
    cdao.executeSql("SELECT CLIENTE.*, ORDEM_DE_SERVICO.*, ORCAMENTO.*, SERVICO.ID AS SERVICO_ID FROM CLIENTE, ORDEM_DE_SERVICO, ORCAMENTO, SERVICO WHERE ORDEM_DE_SERVICO.NUMERO_OS LIKE '874' GROUP BY NUMERO_OS");
    try {
        if (cdao.rs.next()) {

            Cliente c = new Cliente();
            c.setCPF(cdao.rs.getString("CPF"));

            OrdemDeServico ods = new OrdemDeServico();
            ods.setNumeroOS((Integer.valueOf(cdao.rs.getString("NUMERO_OS"))));

            Orcamento o = new Orcamento();
            o.setID(Integer.valueOf(cdao.rs.getString("ID")));
            o.setOrdemDeServicoClienteCpf(c);
            o.setOrdemDeServicoNumeroOS(ods);

            Servico s = new Servico();
            s.setID(Integer.valueOf(cdao.rs.getString("SERVICO_ID")));

            OrcamentoTemServico ots = new OrcamentoTemServico();
            ots.setOrcamentoID(o);
            ots.setNumeroOS(ods);
            ots.setCPF(c);
            ots.setServico(s);
            ots.setQuantidade(1);
            ots.setValor(100);
            ots.setValorTotal(100);

            OrcamentoTemServicoDao otsdao = new OrcamentoTemServicoDao();
            otsdao.insert(ots);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OrcamentoTemServicoDaoTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```